# Trigger alert when expected associated event is not present

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring-query-language

I have two events that should appear in the logs to represent the completion of a transaction. I need to set up an alert when a transaction starts but no completion log entry is found.

What I've done so far is created two user-defined log metrics:

- `order_form_starts` denotes the submission of an order.
- `order_form_sents` denotes the successful transmission of *items* of an order.

  - This entry should be present 1 or more times per `..._start`.

I'm able to query the the events individually but not sure how I can express an alert that should be triggered for the following "BAD" scenarios:

Some examples of possibilities:

- GOOD: start(order_id=1), end(order_id=1)
- GOOD: start(order_id=1), end(order_id=1), end(order_id=1)
- BAD: start(order_id=1)
- BAD: start(order_id=1), end(order_id=2)

Start Event:

```
fetch global::logging.googleapis.com/user/order_form_starts
| group_by [resource.project_id], row_count()
```

[image: screenshot]

End Event:

```
fetch global::logging.googleapis.com/user/order_form_sents
| group_by [resource.project_id], row_count()
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can express it that simply. If I had to implement this, I would create a cloud function that is querying (recurring) the logs for the events and write the result as a [metric (gauge)](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp) into cloud monitoring.

From there you can define a threshold for that metric and create an alert.

You also might want to create traces with [Google Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace) for your transactions where you can keep track of the transactions.